# Define a macro for C struct members

Tags: c, linux

Tried to define a macro to initialize struct member:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DECLARE_MY_STRUCT struct MyStruct {\
    int member1;\
    float member2;\
    union {\
        struct InnerStruct1 option1;\
        struct InnerStruct2 option2;\
    } union_member;\
};

#define MY_STRUCT(init) \
    (struct MyStruct){ init }

struct InnerStruct1 {
    int inner_member1;
    float inner_member2;
};

struct InnerStruct2 {
    char inner_member3;
    double inner_member4;
};

DECLARE_MY_STRUCT

int main() {
    struct MyStruct myStruct = MY_STRUCT({
        .member1 = 10,
        .member2 = 3.14,
        .union_member.option2 = { 'A', 2.718 }
    });

    printf("Initialized values: %d, %.2f, %c, %.3f\n",
           myStruct.member1, myStruct.member2,
           myStruct.union_member.option2.inner_member3,
           myStruct.union_member.option2.inner_member4);

    return 0;
}
```

But I see this error

```
error: macro "MY_STRUCT" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 1
  });
   ^
test_c.c:28:32: error: ‘MY_STRUCT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  struct MyStruct myStruct = MY_STRUCT({
                             ^
```

Is there a way to define to it, without using VAR_ARGS, and just doing type caste stuff ?

Comment: _"Is there a way to define to it, without using VAR_ARGS, and just doing type caste stuff"_ - Perhaps yes, but why not try to solve the problem instead?

Comment: What are you doing with macros? Seems obfuscating.

Comment: What's the point of using a macro for this? You can't use it in multiple places, since you can only declare the struct once. So why not just put the struct declaration there?

Comment: Unless there's something you're not telling us, you're just making life really, really difficult for yourself. Is there some broader problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: C macros do text manipulation, it doesn't always act like you expect for program code, e.g `{\n      .member1 = 10` is treated as the first parameter, etc. This is really not a good way to generate struct initializations, but consider separate parameters if you really need to do this.

Comment: "Is there a way" Yes, just ditch the macros..

Comment: What's the underlying logic/reasoning to using a macro for this, its rather painful looking piece of code that does not offer any benefits, well, maybe, perhaps insanity?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the point of the macros here is to give a minimal failing case (if it's not, then I agree with everyone else--ditch the macros).  Your problem is with the MY_STRUCT macro; the C preprocessor is not smart enough to know that what you have inside the curlies is intended as a single argument.

Also note that the curlies will be included in the expansion; if you change the call on it to:

```
struct MyStruct myStruct = MY_STRUCT({ .member1 = 10 })
```

you will find that the resulting C code is:

```
struct MyStruct myStruct = (struct MyStruct){ { .member1 = 10 } }
```

which will result in a compile error because of the extra curlies.

The cast to (struct MyStruct) is also unneeded and so should not be used--casting is almost never needed and only serves to mask problems.

You will need to use a variadic macro if you want to do this:

```
#define MY_STRUCT(...)   { __VA_ARGS__ }
...
struct MyStruct myStruct = MY_STRUCT(
        .member1 = 10,
        .member2 = 3.14,
        .union_member.option2 = { 'A', 2.718 }
    );
```

will work.

Though again, it's hard for me to see where these macros are actually doing anything useful.  If initializing your struct is complex enough that you want to shove it into a macro, chances are you would be better served to write a function that does it for you--that way you get type checking.  If execution time is an issue, a static inline function should be just as fast as a macro.